# Puxar a ultima informação de uma tabela

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Queria saber como puxar a ultima informação que foi cadastrada no banco, porem não posso usar o ID.

na minha tabela Rota tem as colunas Id(PK), Data, Km_Atual, Combustivel e o NVeiculoId(CK).

Nessa tabela preciso pegar o ultimo Km_Atual digitado e comparar com o que ja estava registrado naquele veiculo que seria o NVeiculoId.

Uso um SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguma ordem é necessário seguir, nesse código eu utilizei a data, e se forem iguais segue a ID.

Com o subselect é gerada a coluna Km_Anterior, feito isso você pode usa-la como quiser.

```
SELECT
ID,
Data,
Km_Atual, 
Combustivel,
NVeiculoID,
    (SELECT TOP 1
         x.Km_Atual 
     FROM rota x 
     WHERE x.NVeiculoID  = r.NVeiculoID
     AND x.ID != r.ID
     AND x.Data < r.Data
     Order By x.Data desc, x.ID desc) as Km_anterior
FROM rota r
```

Comment: Então não irei precisar criar o Km_Anterior? e no lugar da Data não seria o Km_Atual?

Comment: pode ser, lembrando que em ambos os casos, você tem que ter alguma validação disso para que o usuário não informe um km menor que o anterior, ou uma data retroativa com uma km maior que o atual.

Comment: Entendo, necessito colocar essa comparação em um site que estou criando, é em asp.net com linq, antes de eles adicionar ele vai pegar esses valores e comparar, porem é uma tabela de rota então um carro, moto ou veiculo podera andar varias vezes no mesmo dia

Comment: nao vejo problema se o campo data estiver como DateTime, que também irá considerar as horas. Mas se o ID é sequencial e não pode sofrer update na tabela, faria por ele

Comment: Faria pelo date mesmo, entendi, tenta aplica isso ao codigo e agradeço muito pela ajuda

Comment: por nada, não se esqueça de marcar como resposta se te ajudou. =]